# Excel Vlookup - multiple lookup values?

Tags: excel, vlookup

is it possible to use something like this in vlookup() ?

```
=vlookup(or(1,2,3,4), a1:c10, 2)
```

I want to find the first instance in column A that contains the numbers 1-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `VLOOKUP` for this, but you *can* do it with the help of [`MATCH`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a).

Try this (using array formula -> ctrl+shift+enter):

```
{=INDEX(B1:B10,MIN(IFERROR(MATCH({1;2;3;4},A1:A10,0), FALSE)))}
```

The idea is to match against 1-4 to get the index, convert errors to non-errors (`FALSE`), then get the minimum row number. Then that row number is used as an index to the values column.

Comment: Hello Amit; I'm using a charting program that has a built-in spreadsheet program that does not allow using arrays. It would be cumbersome, but would nested if statements be the best option?

Comment: scratch the nested if statements idea, it would not give me the first occurrence of either 1-4...

Comment: What do you mean by "arrays"? What precisely is disallowed?

Comment: @user1947457 - Your comments are unclear. it also seems like your "real" question is **not** what you asked. Please ask about your **real problem** next time so that you get a relevant answer. In the meantime, if my answer is relevant and applicable to the question you did ask, I'd appreciate a vote and / or "accept". Thanks!